# How to set schedule in SharePoint Calendar excluding weekends?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I created a Leave/Paid Time Off Calendar Tracker. I want to **exclude the weekends** in setting up a schedule **without removing it from the calendar**. I use **Start Date** and **End Date** function when setting up a schedule.

Here is where the schedule is based on, was there any workaround that this function exclude weekends?

[image]

For example, the user set **start date** to June 5 (monday) and **end date** to June 12 (monday). I want to **exclude the weekends from being highlighted** in the calendar(Please see the image below).

This is the image of my calendar.
[image]

Comment: I tried that but there is some another issue. Please see on this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217423/sharepoint-calendar-display-problem)