# Need to make sure a Start Date and End date fall within the same work week in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

So basically I am trying to setup a sharepoint time off calendar that will only allow users select a range of time off during the same work week - Monday to Friday only. I have edited the calendar to remove Saturday and Sunday so if a user selects an event lasting more than a week in the date range, the calendar does not display correctly. That is to say since Saturday and Sunday have events the calendar gets broken. Please let me know how I can use formulas to make sure my users can only select a range during a single work week. Or if there is an efficient way to remove weekends from month view that still allows users to select more than a week without breaking the calendar, please let me know. Hopefully I have not confused you :)

Comment: My issue in essence is similar to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218007/how-to-set-schedule-in-sharepoint-calendar-excluding-weekends

Answer (score 0):

Add a list item validation formula. (List Settings, Validation)

This makes several tests:

- Dates must be in the right order.
- Start Date day of week (Tuesday) must be less than End Date day of week (Thursday)
- The dates must be less than six days apart.
- Both dates must not be on weekends.

  ```
  =AND( [End Date] > [Start Date],
    WEEKDAY( [Start Date], 2 ) < WEEKDAY( [End Date], 2 ),
    [End Date] - [Start Date] < 6,
    NOT( OR( WEEKDAY( [Start Date], 2 )=6, WEEKDAY([Start Date],2)=7 ) ),
    NOT( OR( WEEKDAY( [End Date], 2 )=6, WEEKDAY([End Date],2)=7 ) )
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mike's answer, I would recommend including a validation **User Message** to the effect of: "Start must be prior to End, within the same work week, and both must be working days."  Without the validation message, the user only gets  *List Item Validation Failed*.